# Python 3 creating variable names from a list and adding a suffix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I would like to  create a pandas dataframe using the names from a list and then appending '_df' to the end of it but I seem to have two issues. Here is my code below.

```
read_csv = ['apple', 'orange', 'bananna']

for f in read_csv:
    print('DEBUG 7: Value of f inside the loop: ', f)
    ##!!! ERROR HERE - We have reassigned the csv file to f
    ##!!! ERROR HERE - f now contains contents of f.csv(e.g. apple.csv)
    f = pd.read_csv(f + '.csv')
    ##!!! ERROR HERE - Fix above error and the spice shall flow.
    #print('DEBUG 8: Inside read_csv \n', f)
```

The for loop runs and reads in the first item in my list 'apple' and assigns it to f.
We drop into the loop. The first print statement, DEBUG 7, returns the value of f as 'apple'. So far so good.

Next, we run on to the pd.read_csv which is where my first issue is. How do I append '_df' to f? I have read a few answers on here and tried them but it's not working as I expect. I would like to have the loop run and create a new dataframe for apple_df, orange_df and bananna_df. But we can come back to that.

The second error I get here is "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1" The CSV file has 8 columns and that is getting assigned to f instead of the dataframe name.
I can't for the life of me work out what's occurring to make that happen. Well, I can. If I fix the apple_df issue I believe the dataframe will read in the csv file fine.

Still learning so all help is appreciated.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `locals()` to create local variables (apple_df, orange_df, ...)

```
read_csv = ['apple', 'orange', 'bananna']

for f in read_csv:
    locals()[f"{f}_df"] = pd.read_csv(f"{f}.csv")
```

```
>>> type(apple_df)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Comment: Hi. I like this method. 2 questions. how do you deal with a list item that has a full stop in its name 'apple' which becomes appl.e_df and will then throw an error
```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'dark' is not defined
```
second question: how do I reference my new auto generated dataframe names. -f['Returns'] = (f['Close'] - f['Open']) / f['Open'] ?

Comment: Your variable names need to be a valid python identifier else use a dictionary to store your dataframe which each key is the name of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

> ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1

You got that error because you can't assign DataFrame to `f` variable which is a string in that loop. You have to store it into new variable, for exaple `df`

```
df = pd.read_csv(f + '.csv')
```

If you want to create new variable by `f` and `"_df"` you need to use [`exec`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/exec)

```
exec(f + "_df" + " = pd.read_csv(f + '.csv')")
```

Comment: This worked but gave a similar error to my selected answer. I didn't handle having a fullstop in the name. e.g appl.e